# Word frequency and line number in Java

Tags: java, regex, key, frequency, cpu-word

> Write a program using Java or C# that counts the frequencies of each
>   word in a text, and output each word with its count and line numbers
>   where it appears. We define a word as a contiguous sequence of
>   non-white-space characters. (hint: split()) Note: different
>   capitalizations of the same character sequence should be considered
>   same word, e.g. Python and python, I and i. The input will be several
>   lines with the empty line terminating the text (using text file for
>   input is optional). Only alphabet characters and white spaces will be
>   present in the input. The output is formatted as follows:
>
> ```
> - 1 python 1
> - 3 is 1 2
> - 1 a 1
> - 1 but 1
> - 1 cool 1 2
> - 1 even 2
> - 1 object 2
> - 1 oriented 2
> - 1 it 2
> - 1 language 1 2
> - 1 Java 1
> - 1 purely 2
> - 1 since 2
> ```

This is what I have:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String text = "Python is a cool language but Java \n" +
        "is also cool since it is purely object oriented language ";
        String[] keys = text.split(" ");
        String[] uniqueKeys;
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println(text);
        uniqueKeys = getUniqueKeys(keys);
        int line2 = text.indexOf('\n');

        for(String key: uniqueKeys)
        {
            if(null == key)
            {
                break;
            }           
            for(String s : keys)
            {
                if(key.equals(s))
                {
                    count++;
                }               
            }

            System.out.println(count +" "+ key);
            count=0;
        }
    }

    private static String[] getUniqueKeys(String[] keys)
    {
        String[] uniqueKeys = new String[keys.length];

        uniqueKeys[0] = keys[0];
        int uniqueKeyIndex = 1;
        boolean keyAlreadyExists = false;

        for(int i=1; i<keys.length ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<=uniqueKeyIndex; j++)
            {
                if(keys[i].equals(uniqueKeys[j]))
                {
                    keyAlreadyExists = true;
                }
            }           

            if(!keyAlreadyExists)
            {
                uniqueKeys[uniqueKeyIndex] = keys[i];
                uniqueKeyIndex++;               
            }
            keyAlreadyExists = false;
        }       
        return uniqueKeys;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to get the output to include the line numbers of each word as well. Thanks for any help. I am using Java by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Set;

 public class Countcharacters {

/**
 * @param args
 */
static HashMap<String, Integer> countcharact=new HashMap<>();
static HashMap<String, String> linenumbertrack=new HashMap<>();
static int count=1;
static void countwords(String line){
    //System.out.println(line);
    String[] input=line.split("\\s");
    int j=0;
    String linenumber="";
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        //System.out.println(input[i]);
        if(countcharact.containsKey(input[i])==true){
            j=countcharact.get(input[i]);
            linenumber=linenumbertrack.get(input[i]);
            countcharact.put(input[i],j+1);
            linenumbertrack.put(input[i],linenumber+" "+count);

        }
        else{
            countcharact.put(input[i], 1);
            linenumbertrack.put(input[i],count+" " );
        }

    }
    count++;


}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   String inp="its am here in 1st line\ni am here in 2nd line";
   String[] line=inp.split("\n");
   for(int i=0;i<line.length;i++){
       Countcharacters.countwords(line[i]);
   }
    Set<String> s=countcharact.keySet();
    for(String c:s){
        System.out.println(countcharact.get(c)+" "+c+" "+linenumbertrack.get(c));
    }



}
```

}

Idea is to use 2 hashmap. One to store words and occurences and another is store the word and line number it occured. Combining these both hashmap to get the required output.

Output of the above program:

1 2nd 2

2 am 1  2

1 1st 1

2 line 1  2

2 here 1  2

1 its 1

2 in 1  2

1 i 2

Answer (score 0):

This is *much* simpler if you model a word plus its occurance data as an object and make use of the java collections framework.

For a word you want to know how often it occurs, and *where* it occurs, so a WordData class may look like this:

```
public class WordData {
    public String theWord;
    public List<Integer> appearsWhere = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Note that I didnt include the count of appearances, because thats equal to the number of places where it appears, namely `appearsWhere.size()`. I also omitted getters/setters.

Now for keeping track of multiple words, you want a map, word plays the key, and the WordData is the value `Map<String, WordData> wordMap = new HashMap<>()`. To locate a words data, just use `wordMap.get(String)`, if that return null the word doesn't exist yet, so you create it and put it in the map. Otherwise just add the place where it appears to the WordData.

So the whole program runs like this:

```
for each word {
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    WordData wd = wordMap.get(word);
    if (wd == null) {
        wd = new WordData();
        wd.theWord = word;
        wordMap.put(word, wd);
    }
    wd.appearsWhere.add(currentPlace);
}
```

To output all data, just iterate over the maps values and in a nested loop over the appearsWhere:

```
for (WordData wd : wordMap) {
    // output count and word
    for (Integer where : wd.appearsWhere) {
        // output where
    }
}
```

Using Map and List you needn't worry about managing the storage for the data in detail, these classes take care of that. You can just focus on the logic which is very simple.